# Graph Coloring Question With Zoo

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

A zoo is going to place its animals in a set of large open areas, instead of having
them in individual cages. If two different animals cannot live together peacefully
(e.g., a tiger and deer cannot live together because the tiger will eat the deer), then
they must be put in different open areas. The zoo wants to determine the minimum
number of open areas needed to safely house all its animals. Model this problem
of assigning animals to a minimal number of open areas as a graph-coloring
problem. What are the vertices, what are the edges, what are the colors?

This problem isn't asking me to solve the graph coloring. It's just asking me to identify the vertices, edges and colors correct? In which the vertices are the animals, the edges are the animals that can't live together peacefully as they will attack each other, and the colors are the areas needed to safely house all the animals correct?

Comment: correct $()()()()()()$

Comment: Deer can live peacefully with tigers. It is  tigers  who cannot live peacefully with anybody.

Comment: "as they will attack each other".  No!  Tigers will attack deer, deer do not attack tigers!

Comment: Oh okay, so correct revision would be, they just can't live peacefully (no other info added). Correct?